# How to implement a module system for a language like JS?

Tags: module, compiler-construction, programming-languages

Currently, I've learnt to write my own compiler following this guide: https://craftinginterpreters.com/. But the author did not mention how to implement a module system for the language. I also cannot find any tutorial that is straightforward on the internet to let me know what I should learn to implement this.

Really appreciate if somebody know any good material on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find a good tutorial on building a module system because there isn't a consensus on what a good module system looks like, and also because a lot of details will depend on the precise nature of your language.

What you will find, if you look, are long discussions about how to fix the broken module system for different languages. You'll find those discussions because almost every language has started with a module system (or had a module system attach itself) which didn't work as desired. Practically every language has had to either implement a new module system along the way, with consequent backwards-compatibility issues, or resign itself to whatever uncorrectable flaws showed up in the original implementation. You'll learn a lot by reading these discussions.

Part of the reason for this is that many languages were designed by programmers with little or no experience with a reasonable module system. Try not to fall into this category. If you have experience with one ir more module systems, build on that experience to design a better one. And read as much as you can find from credible critics of those systems.

And don't expect to get it perfect the first time :-) Make sure you exercise your system a lot while you're still in the design phase and able to make adjustments without prejudicing legacy code.

Good luck!